# My 2009 Chevy Traverse has a cylinder shot and Timing belt is there a time stamp or on board history on when it went out

Tags: cylinder

Is there a time stamp or history on when a cylinder or timing 
Chain went out

Comment: You could check the PCM data. In some cases GMs will store time/miles since the code was set. If the PCM has been reset there may be a time/miles since cleared.

Answer (score 0):

If the ecu stored an error code when the belt failed it does not come with a time or data stamp as far as I have seen on the cars I have had with fault code systems (VW and Ford / Jaguar).